Inside mount cordless blinds with clips on top
I am struggling with what should have been a simple task and I surprisingly did not find any Youtube videos that covered my scenario exactly.
I am trying to inside mount cordless blinds in a bathroom window. The blinds came with clips that go on the top and mount into the top window trim with 2 screws per bracket. My window frame has what feels like a thin wood piece on top with empty space behind it. The mounting instructions called for simply screwing into the top surface, but the bracket pulled out after a few days of use as I had expected. You can see the mounting holes and the mounting surface in this picture.
What would be the best way to mount the blinds? I thought I'll just use longer screws and hit the wood at some point, but when I poked inside with a drill bit, it felt like there was a lot of empty space there before I eventually hit what felt like insulation (I felt some bounce). I also thought about using toggle bolts, but mounting holes are too close to each other considering how thin the top trim feels to be. I don't think I can use standard drywall anchors either, right?


Did you pre-drill the screw holes and maybe drill the holes too big?   The wood frame should be a 1x and plenty thick enough to hold the screws.   Did you try fatter screws?  Remember the left side is holding

@RMDman The instructions called for predrilling holes, and I drilled them one notch smaller than the instructions called for. The other side is holding (for now) but it is loose.

If the screws are loose or fall out the predrilled hole is too big for the screws used.  It's simple physics. Too much material was removed for the screw threads to grip. There is not enough frictional resistance.  This is true of any screw that does not stay tight in any wood hole.

You need to go shopping for Hollow-Wall Anchors, Drywall Anchor
Specially made for your situation
They look like this (the one on the left

Found on anchor

Something ain't right with that pic—the one on the right.  How would that even be installed?

I looked at the anchors and most of them require at least 1.4" hole. I am concerned about cranking that wood piece if I drill 1/4" holes that close to each other.
